# my mobile is not showing memory card?

Tags: sd-card

I have samsung pocket GTS-5300,  suddenly it's showing a message of not enough space. 4 gb memory card inserted in it. But it's not showing the card's space. no messages are coming nd everytime my phone is showing message of not enough space.
so tell me how this problem be sovled.

Comment: Share the screenshot of the message or quote it **exactly**. Also, see similar and possibly helpful [tag:insufficient-memory] tagged Q/A.